# Podio API: how long are unattached files retained?

Tags: podio

When I upload a file to Podio using Podio API and do **not** attach it to anything, is the file kept forever or is there a time limit?

Answer (score 0):

I've never run across an upward limit. I know there is a limit with Podio Items on free organizations, but I don't think there is a limit to the file attachments for even those free users.

For those files to be useful, you'd need to keep a database of the File IDs somewhere. I don't know that there is a way to fetch files for a particular user instead of something like an Item/Space/Comment/Status/etc.

Comment: Thanks. Well, it seems the files are retained at lest for a couple of months. Granted, it's a pretty obscure use case to have them unattached, but for API tinkering it's sometimes useful.